# Multiple Target Id's and the ModalPopUp Extender

Tags: javascript, ajax, modalpopupextender, confirmbuttonextender

Evening all.

Ok, here we go!

Right I have the following buttons on my page and I wish to use one modal popup for both save clicks. I therefore have the following for the buttons:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave1" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave1_Click" Text="Save" OnClientClick="$find('showSaveConfirm').show(); return false;" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSave2" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave2_Click" Text="Save" OnClientClick="$find('showSaveConfirm').show(); return false;"/>

<asp:Button ID="btnSaveAll" runat="server" Text="" Style="display: none" />
```

And this below is my Modal panel info:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSaveConfirm" runat="server" Style="display: none;" CssClass="modalPopupContainer">
            <div id="Div7" class="modalPopupHeaderPanel">
                <div id="Div8" class="modalPopupHeader">

                </div>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopupClose" CausesValidation="False">Cancel and close</asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
            <div id="Div9" class="modalPopupBannerPanel">
                <div class="modalPopupPanel">
                        <br />
                        You are about to save this piece of data.
                        <asp:Button ID="btnOkSave" runat="server" Text="Ok" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCancelSave" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                        <br />
        </asp:Panel>
        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPopupSaveConfirm" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnSaveAll" BehaviorID="showSaveConfirm"
            OkControlID="btnOkSave" CancelControlID="btnCancelSave" PopupControlID="pnlSaveConfirm" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
```

Now both clicks fire off the one modal panel which is spot on. The cancels, cancel but there is one problem.

When I click on the btnOkSave, this does not appear to be confirming as the btnSave1_Click and btnSave2_Click server side events do not get fired off.

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I actually went down a slightly different route and seeing as I was using the Ajax toolkit, I implemented the use of the ConfirmButtonExtender.

For the two original saves, I set up two seperate ModalPopUpExtenders pointing at the same panel, these being executed by the ConfirmButton Extender:

```
  <ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender1" 
                    runat="server" ConfirmText="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="btnSave1" DisplayModalPopupID="mdlPopupSave1Confirm">
                </ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender>
<ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender2" 
                    runat="server" ConfirmText="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="btnSave2" DisplayModalPopupID="mdlPopupSave2Confirm">
                </ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender>
```

With these attached to the actual panel:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPopupSave1Confirm" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnSave1"
             OkControlID="btnOkSave" CancelControlID="btnCancelSave"
            PopupControlID="pnlSaveConfirm" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPopupSave2Confirm" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnSave2"
             OkControlID="btnOkSave" CancelControlID="btnCancelSave"
            PopupControlID="pnlSaveConfirm" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
```

And that has achieved exactly what I am looking to do.

Still dirty but it works :  )

Answer (score 1):

There is no OnClick event for btnOkSave.  Add this to your control:

```
OnClick="btnSave1_Click"
```

Comment: True that. 

However, what I am trying to achieve is that each btnSave1, btnSave2 two fires off the same modal panel but seperate btnSave1_Click, btnSave1_Click events.

If I just give btnOkSave - btnSave1_Click, btnSave2_Click won't fire if I click btnOkSave.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see what you mean.  There's no easy way to do this with ASP controls.  My suggestion would be to use one click event and add it to btnOkSave.  Set up an asp:HiddenField control that will contain a value that corresponds with whatever Save button they just clicked.  Set an OnClientClick to a javascript function that updates the asp:HiddenField with the save button that they clicked.  Then you can access what save event logic to execute in your singular btnSave_Click event based on the value of your asp:HiddenField.

Dirty, but effective.

Comment: Dammit! That is pretty filthy but at least it will work : )

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Dirty is as dirty does, just like any client-side ASP work.  Switch to MVC3 ;)

Comment: That's on my very long "to do" list Kamojoe